Serialize a JSON Object to Dictionary<string, string>
I have an object of the following class structure:
public class Customer
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Address contact { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string city { get; set; }
}

and I want the following expected output:
Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "ID",  "1" },
    { "contact.city", "Miami" }
};

but I fail because of a nested class structure.
Exception:

Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'contact', line 1, position 21.
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)

My code:
Customer customer = new Customer() { ID = "1",  contact = new Address() { city = "Miami" } };
string customerString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
Dictionary<string, string> result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(customerString);

Question:
How to achieve this output?
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q34OxD

@DA I totally solves my problem

AFAIK, Newtonsoft.Json does not support (de)serialization for flattened JSON.
You have to implement additional logic to flatten JSON.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;

public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> FlattenObject<T>(T source)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        return JObject.FromObject(source)
            .Descendants()
            .OfType<JValue>()
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Path, v => v.Value<string>());
    }
}

Caller:
Dictionary<string, string> result = JsonHelper.FlattenObject(JObject.Parse(customerString));

You can provide the customer instance directly without serialized JSON:
Dictionary<string, string> result = JsonHelper.FlattenObject(customer);


Demo @ .NET Fiddle
